# Getting run time error after upgrading the spring version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-couchbase

Getting below runtime error in postman after upgraded to 5.0.19.RELEASE version of spring and bouncycastle to  jdk15 version 1.68.

Please advice.

JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
```

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

```
JBWEB000068: message java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
```

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:369)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:237)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:598)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:565)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:130)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    
JBWEB000071: root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;
[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class; 
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory$PropertyAccessorClassGenerator.generateCustomAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:336) 
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.createAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:198) 
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.potentiallyCreateAndRegisterPersistentPropertyAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:184) 
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:92) 
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:453) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getPropertyAccessor(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:820) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:238) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:214) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:172) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:78) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.mapToEntity(CouchbaseTemplate.java:713) 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findById(CouchbaseTemplate.java:323) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:583) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:565) 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:130) 
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) 
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) 
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```